# Android application out of memory error, trying to use an 88kb image

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, android-studio, memory-leaks

I'm trying to use an **image** for a tutorial section of my android application and when I click on the **Button** that sends me to the tutorial **Activity** the screen goes black and the log gives me this error

```
  E/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Out of memory on a 149299216-byte allocation
```

The image size is 88kb,

i have tried changing the manifest and adding large heap which gets rid of the error but it just has a blank white screen apposed to the image (although the scrolling of the scrollview in the tutorial activity is set to the correct height of the image which is odd)

I have also tried a 60kb smaller version of the image which doesnt give an error but gives a blank white screen also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a good library to show your image.I suggest you [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
,It handle image size and memory and many other things.
also there is another library that work in same way,[UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: Thanks for the response, can I ask if it is complicated to use Picasso? Is there an easier way to load images?

Comment: you should use it or you should do it by yourself,if you choose second approach I think it's more harder for you. in that case you need to re size image and add Bitmap option to it and...

Comment: using Picasso is toooooooo simple just add library and call Picasso.with(context).load("your image").into(imageView);

Comment: I'm getting the same out of memory error with Picasso

Comment: actually in my case I use UIL ,i update answer above.by UIL I load 4MB image with 3000*1500 pixel size.(in Picasso you need more customization)

Comment: UIL looks more complicated haha :/

Answer (score 0):

add property in your mainifast file

```
<application

    android:largeHeap="true"

</application>
```

Comment: I said in the question i have tried this to no avail